# Imageview relative layout - changes position on picture taken

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, android-relativelayout

I have an imageview whose image([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlwDO.jpg)) is loaded from a asset file onCreateInstance() and the same imageview is rotated and loaded with the images taken from a camera[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvzcu.jpg) (using camera API on picture taken). The imageview changes position when rotated and moves around every time i take a new picture.

Here is the relative layout  structure:

```
<RelativeLayout 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MainPage" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dip"
    android:onClick="uploadFile"
    android:text="Upload" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ins"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Please scan the QR code on the package to retrieve the package ID"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ins"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:onClick="scan"
    android:text="Scan" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/captureFront"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Camera" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageView"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The following code shows how the imageview is loaded with images (programatically)

```
    imageView.setImageBitmap(loadDataFromAsset());

    public Bitmap loadDataFromAsset() {
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = getAssets().open("signBG.jpeg");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    return bmp;

}
```

The above code is called via OnCreateInstance() and

The following code updates the imageview onResume

```
    @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setImage();
}
```

and when the activity resumes (OnResume())

```
     private void setImage(){
    if(constants.picTaken){
        bitmap = loadPicture("sign.jpeg", bitmap) ;
        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        uploadButton.setEnabled(true);
        insLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ins);
        insLabel.setText("Please upload on confirmation");



        if (bitmap != null) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageView.setPivotX(imageView.getHeight()/2);
            imageView.setPivotY(imageView.getWidth()/2);
            imageView.setRotation(90);




        }
    }
}
```

Please do refer to the two images i have linked, for references.
        Can the images look consistent as seen loading from the asset file?

Comment: Note that both image links are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much a shot in the dark since I can't see both images until the link is fixed in the question.

The problem might be with the rotation, which I believe is occurring after the `ImageView` is positioned in the layout, then rotated 90 degrees around it's center. Here that rotation pivot is the center of the view if it wouldn't have been rotated.

If that is the case, the best suggestion would be to rotate the bitmap that is being use in the view, instead of rotating the view.

Comment: I have made the changes.

Comment: Your shot in the dark did hit the target